# How Kafka sink supports update mode in structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have read about the different output modes like:

**Complete Mode** - The entire updated Result Table will be written to the sink. 
**Append Mode** - Only the new rows appended in the Result Table since the last trigger will be written to the external storage. 
**Update Mode** - Only the rows that were updated in the Result Table since the last trigger will be written to the external storage

At first I thought I understand the above explanations.

Then I come across this:

**File sink supported modes:** Append 
**Kafka sink supported modes:** Append,Update,Complete

Wait!! What??!!

Why couldn't we just write out the entire result table to file?
How can we an already existing entry in Kafka update? It's a stream, you can't just look for certain messages and change/update them.

This makes no sense at all.
Could you help me understand this? I just dont get how this works technically

Answer (score 1):

Spark writes one file per partition, often with one file per executor. Executors run in a distributed fashion. Files are local to each executor, so append just makes sense - you cannot full replace individual files, especially without losing data within the stream. So that leaves you with "appending *new files to the filesystem*", or inserting into existing files.

Kafka has no update functionality... [Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) doesn't mention any of these modes, so it is unclear what you are referring to. You use `write` or `writeStream`. It will always "append" the "complete" dataframe batch(es) to the end of the Kafka topic. The way Kafka implements something like updates is using [compacted topics](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction), but this has nothing to do with Spark.

Comment: Thanks your response.
For the file one : it is clear now, thx.
for the Kafka:   here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks  there is a table which lists the different sinks. And for the Kafka it says all of the three output modes - including update - is supported

Comment: Okay, so those modes refer to [Spark's "Result Tables"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-concepts), not the outbound sinks.